# Google Sheets: Consolidate Rows By Unique ID

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to consolidate crypto data from BscScan, by ID (a Hash in this case).  As the downloaded data has many irrelevant columns, and actual hash data is very long, I've created a simple abbreviated data example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

**For each Hash**, I need to

1. Sum the "Number" column
2. Count the Number of Records

Some pointers on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

```
=QUERY(A2:B14, "select A, sum(B), count(B) 
                 where A <>'' group by A 
                 label sum(B) 'Total', count(B) 'Record Count' ",1)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  I'm getting too old,  completely forgot about using QUERY().  Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. You're just getting wiser. Can't fit it all :)